# MiniProfiler "Share" Link Shows Nothing

Tags: c#, mvc-mini-profiler

When I click on "Share" the screen it loads has no content. Even when I view source there isn't anything.

I've set `MiniProfiler.Settings.Results_Authorize = r => true;` in global.asax BeginRequest

When I set auth to false it shows "hidden" so I know the request is being  routed to the MiniProfiler handler.

Any ideas?

[image: Share Link]

[image: No Content]

Comment: That's odd. Is this a single machine? or a cluster? In the latter case, you need to implement a trivial interface with your choice of back-end store, so that if the initial / share requests go to different machines it still makes sense (the default implementation is in-memory) - are you sure it isn't just this?

Comment: @MarcGravell Fairly certain. Right now I am simply running it locally on my machine. The plan is to deploy it to our web farm next week. In preparation for this I've been using SqlServerStorage. I also tried it using the default HttpRuntimeCacheStorage though, and it still didn't work. You can see in my answer below that building the latest source fixed it. This was true for both IStorage implementations. I'm satisfied using the latest source build. If you want more info for yourself please just let me know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: k; thanks. We're going to try and re-deploy it this weekend. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @MarcGravell No problem at all. Thank you for making such a great tool! Super slick use of interfaces and static properties in MiniProfiler.Settings. It has been a breeze to set up and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I fixed it...ish. Or rather they fixed it.

Apparently this is a bug in the NuGet dll's.

When I download the source from miniprofiler.com, build it, and click on "share" everything works great.

[image: Source Code]